# Mock axios when using the axios constuctor function

Tags: mocking, jestjs, axios

I have an API utility function that calls axios using the constructor notation:

```js
axios({
   method,
   url: `${BASE_URL}/${url}`,
   data
});
```

I want to mock this using Jest, but not quite sure how. I was only able to mock a specific axios function (get, post, etc.).

Does anyone have an example of mocking axios when using it this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [jest.mock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) to mock `axios` function.

E.g.

`index.js`:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

export function main() {
  const BASE_URL = 'https://stackoverflow.com';
  const url = 'api';
  const data = {};
  return axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: `${BASE_URL}/${url}`,
    data,
  });
}
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
import { main } from '.';
import axios from 'axios';

jest.mock('axios', () => jest.fn());

describe('59873406', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const mResponse = { data: 'mock data' };
    axios.mockResolvedValueOnce(mResponse);
    const response = await main();
    expect(response).toEqual(mResponse);
    expect(axios).toBeCalledWith({ method: 'GET', url: 'https://stackoverflow.com/api', data: {} });
  });
});
```

Unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/59873406/index.test.js
  59873406
    ✓ should pass (7ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.362s, estimated 13s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59873406

Comment: When I do this, I get an error saying axios.mockResolvedValueOnce is not a function. Package "jest": "^29.3.1",, "axios": "0.27.2"

Comment: @Kesava Do you use TypeScript? Is this a runtime error or compiler time error?

Comment: I receive the same and yes, its a typescript error. "Property 'mockResolvedValue' does not exist on type 'AxiosStatic'."