# Async Testing axios in node, and getting a timeout error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I have my Axios code, which should download a file (cribbed and changed from [here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/download-files-images-with-axios-in-node-js)).

```js
'use strict'

const Fs = require('fs')
const Path = require('path')
const axios = require('axios')

const URL = 'https://unsplash.com/photos/AaEQmoufHLk/download?force=true'

async function downloadMtgJson() {
    const path = Path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources', 'code.jpg')
    const writer = Fs.createWriteStream(path)

    const response = await axios({
        URL,
        method: 'GET',
        responseType: 'stream'
    })
    console.log(response.data.pipe)
    if (response && response.data) response.data.pipe(writer);
    console.log('hello')
    return handleWriter(writer)
}
const handleWriter = (writer) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    writer.on('finish', resolve)
    writer.on('error', reject)
})
module.exports = {
    downloadMtgJson,
    handleWriter,
    URL
}
```

And I looked for [an example of axios tests](https://www.robinwieruch.de/axios-jest) for this online, and some [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59873406/mock-axios-when-using-the-axios-constuctor-function), and found some code I've also tweaked to my purposes:

```js
const axios = require('axios');

const { downloadMtgJson, URL } = require('./resources');

jest.mock('axios');

describe.only('fetchData', () => {
    it('fetches successfully data from an URL', async () => {
        expect.assertions(1);
        const data = { status: 200, data: { pipe: () => 'data' } };

        axios.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(data));
        console.log('waiting...')
        await expect(downloadMtgJson()).resolves.toEqual('data');
        console.log('waited')
        expect(axios).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
            `${URL}/search?query=react`,
        );
    });
});
```

The issue I am having, is that the promise part of the `handleWriter` seems to be timing out. At one point I mocked it in the same way as I mocked axios, but it didn't make a difference.

> Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:

```
       6 | 
       7 | describe.only('fetchData', () => {
    >  8 |     it('fetches successfully data from an URL', async () => {
```

I can't figure out what is different in what I've done, vs what I've seen in testing examples.

What can I do to get my tests working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is also asynchronous:

```js
 const writer = Fs.createWriteStream(path)
```

And needs mocking out to prevent the error you see.

The full test code is now:

```js
   jest.mock('fs');
   jest.mock('axios');
   jest.mock('./resource.util')

// ... other code ...

    it('fetches successfully data from an URL', async () => {
        const data = { status: 200, data: { pipe: () => 'data' } };

        axios.mockImplementationOnce(() => data);
        fs.createWriteStream.mockImplementationOnce(() => 'fs');
        handleWriter.mockImplementationOnce(() => 'data'); //handle writer was extracted to a util file
        const expectedJson = await downloadMtgJson();
        expect(expectedJson).toEqual('data');
        expect(axios).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
            expect.objectContaining({ URL: 'https://unsplash.com/photos/AaEQmoufHLk/download?force=true' }),
        );
        expect(axios).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
            expect.objectContaining({ responseType: 'stream' }),
        );
    });
```