# TypeError: axios is not a function - By running test Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, jestjs

I am facing an error when I am trying to use post request using axios in nodejs.
It keep giving me error when I run test: TypeError: axios is not a function
It refers to line "const axios = require('axios');" in requestToken function.

service.js

```
    const axios = require('axios');
    const qs = require('qs');
    
    const requestToken = async (apiURL, reqBody) => {
      const postBody = qs.stringify({
        client_id: reqBody.client_id,
        client_secret: reqBody.client_secret,
        grant_type: reqBody.grant_type,
        'content-type': reqBody.content_type,
      });
      const postHeaders = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': JSON.stringify(postBody).length,
        Host: new URL(apiURL).hostname,
        Connection: 'keep-alive',
      };
      const config = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: apiURL,
        headers: postHeaders,
        data: postBody,
      };
      const response = await axios(config); //it refers to the error here
      return response;
    };
```

Here is my test file:
service.test.js

```
const qs = require('qs');
const axios = require('axios');
const {requestToken } = require('../../libs/service');

const apiConfig = {
  TOKEN_REQ_BODY: {
    client_id: 'client_id',
    client_secret: 'client_secret',
    grant_type: 'grant_type',
    content_type: 'content_type',
  },
  AUTH_BASE_URL: 'uri',
  TOKEN_HEADER: {
    appkey: 'appkey',
  },
  API_BASE_URL: 'API_BASE_URL',
};
const tokenAxiosCalledWith = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: apiConfig.AUTH_BASE_URL,
  headers: apiConfig.TOKEN_HEADER,
  data: qs.stringify({
    client_id: apiConfig.TOKEN_REQ_BODY.client_id,
    client_secret: apiConfig.TOKEN_REQ_BODY.client_secret,
    grant_type: apiConfig.TOKEN_REQ_BODY.grant_type,
    'content-type': apiConfig.TOKEN_REQ_BODY.content_type,
  }),
};
const accessToken = {
  data: {
    access_token: 'access_token',
  },
};
const eventData = {
  metadata: {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'uri',
  },
  uriparams: 'uriparams',
  payload: tokenAxiosCalledWith.data,
};
const requestHeaders = {
  Authorization: accessToken.data.access_token,
  appkey: apiConfig.TOKEN_HEADER.appkey,
  'content-type': 'application/json',
};
const reqBody = {
  method: eventData.metadata.method,
  baseURL: apiConfig.API_BASE_URL,
  url: eventData.metadata.uri,
  responseType: 'json',
  headers: requestHeaders,
  params: eventData.uriparams,
  data: eventData.payload,
};
jest.mock('axios', () => jest.fn(() => accessToken));

describe('API service', () => {
it('is called with requestToken', (done) => {
    /* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
    requestToken('https://token', reqBody).then((response) => {
      expect(axios).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      done();})
      .catch((e) => {
        done(e);
        });
    });
}
```

Can you help to fix this error?

Comment: Immediately after importing the axios library, what is the value of axios.VERSION?

Comment: @jarmod "axios": "^1.0.0"

Comment: @jarmod axios.VERSION: "1.1.3"

Comment: Might be caused by your attempt to mock axios. See the example [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-modules) and perhaps use the explicit `axios.post(...)` method instead of the `axios({method:"POST", ...})` constructor variant? Also, see [Mock axios when using the axios constuctor function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59873406/mock-axios-when-using-the-axios-constuctor-function).